# Accessing QT text in lineEdit

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have a form with 2 widgets. One `LineEdit` (name : `lineEdit`) and `Button`  (name `pushButton_2`).
Below my code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui  

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 70, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 10, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton_2, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), myFunc)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Press me!", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want make a function so I press `button` it will get value text form `LineEdit`  widget. Like the following:

```
def myfunc():
    text=Get_Value_From_Widget()
    ...........
    return text
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can code this simple widget manually, without using QtDesigner. It may be a little harder at first, but it will be worth it in the long run, as you gain a much finer control on what you do.

Here is a simple example of what you may want to do.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class CustomWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QtGui.QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.lineEdit1 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit1)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton("line1 -> line2", self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClick)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.lineEdit2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit2)

    def onClick(self):
        self.lineEdit2.setText(self.lineEdit1.text())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = CustomWidget()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you should look at the Qt documentation about SIGNAL/SLOT mechanism.

Anyway, your function should be defined into the `Ui_Form` class as

```
def myFunc(self):
    text=self.lineEdit.text()
    return text
```

Please note that the code is case sensitive (as the name of the methods/functions) so in your case `myFunc` is not the same method as `myfunc`

Comment: I tried to add function  into the Ui_Form class  with two different types def myFunc(self,Form): and  def myFunc(self) : . But i get error "AttributeError: 'Ui_Form' object has no attribute 'myFunc'"